# Chromium Embedded (CEF3). How to resize new browser window?

Tags: visual-c++, tabs, resize, popup, chromium-embedded

So i'm using CEF v3.1180.823 and i'm trying to make browser with multiple tabs.

For every new tab i'm:

1) creating a new window with style WS_POPUPWINDOW.

```
HWND hWndTab = CreateWindowEx(NULL, w.lpszClassName, 0,
    WS_POPUPWINDOW, x, y, width, height, 
    NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

2) creating a new "g_handler"

```
CefRefPtr<ClientHandler> cef_hTab = new ClientHandler();
```

3) creating new browser

```
CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(info, cef_hTab.get(), _url, settings);
```

4) setting this window as child for first (main) tab that never closes

```
SetParent(hWndTab, g_handler->GetMainHwnd());
```

5) Setting the HWND of new window as main HWND for new handler

```
cef_hTab->SetMainHwnd(hWndTab);
```

**My problem is**: how do i resize all of my tabs when main window is resizing?

The default window procedure (i.e. procedure of main tab) has this code:

```
case WM_SIZE:
        // Minimizing resizes the window to 0x0 
        // which causes our layout to go all
        // screwy, so we just ignore it.
        if (wParam != SIZE_MINIMIZED && 
            g_handler.get() && 
            g_handler->GetBrowser()) 
        {
            CefWindowHandle hwnd = 
                g_handler->GetBrowser()->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();
            if (hwnd) 
            {
                // Resize the browser window and 
                // address bar to match the new frame
                // window size
                RECT rect;
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

                rect.top += URLBAR_HEIGHT;

                int urloffset = rect.left + BUTTON_WIDTH * 4;

                HDWP hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos(1);
                hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, hwnd, NULL, rect.left, rect.top, 
                    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
                EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);
            }
        }
        break;
```

I have a std::list of my tabs:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include "include/cef_app.h"
#include "cefclient/binding_test.h"

using namespace std;

struct STab
{
    HWND                        hWndTab;
    HWND                        hWndTabButton;
    CefRefPtr<ClientHandler>    cef_handler;

    void Destroy();
};

typedef list<STab> LTabs;

LTabs* GetTabs();
```

And i'm trying to edit the main window procedure like this:

```
case WM_SIZE:
        if (wParam != SIZE_MINIMIZED && 
            g_handler.get() && 
            g_handler->GetBrowser()) 
        {
            CefWindowHandle hwnd = 
                g_handler->GetBrowser()->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();
            if (hwnd) 
            {
                RECT rect;
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

                rect.top += URLBAR_HEIGHT;

                int urloffset = rect.left + BUTTON_WIDTH * 4;

                HDWP hdwp = BeginDeferWindowPos(1);
                hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, hwnd, NULL, rect.left, rect.top, 
                    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
                // added:
                //------------------------------------------------------------------
                LTabs* lTabs = GetTabs();
                LTabs::iterator it;
                for (it = lTabs->begin(); it != lTabs->end(); ++it)
                {
                    CefWindowHandle hWndTab = 
                        it->cef_handler->GetBrowser()->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();
                    if (hWndTab)
                        hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, hWndTab, NULL, 
                            rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, 
                            rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);                      
                }
                //------------------------------------------------------------------
                EndDeferWindowPos(hdwp);
            }
        }
        break;
```

But on resizing main window it resizes neither main tab nor my custom tabs.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, you could post your solution and accept it as answer. You answer may help many other programmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution is to use `SetWindowPos` function instead of `DeferWindowPos` function.

```
//hdwp = DeferWindowPos(hdwp, hWndTab, NULL, 
//                      rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, 
//                      rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowPos(hWndTab, NULL, rect.left, rect.top, 
             rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 
             SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```